# PHP pdo and security for taking data (insert)

Tags: php, security, pdo

I am making a website with just a simple form where i can get some data for people who want to reserve a table for a quiz. Everything works fine, but i don't know much about security for it. After my own research i ended with PDO for my php code, but does anyone know if this is good? (everything works it's just about security

```html
ob_start();
include 'connect.php';
$naam = $_POST['naam'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$personen = $_POST['aantal'];
$telefoonnummer = $_POST['phone'];
$bedrijf = $_POST['bedrijf'];

if($bedrijf != 1){
  $bedrijf = 0;
}
if (empty($naam) || empty($email) || empty($personen) || empty($telefoonnummer)) {
    header("Location: ../form.php?error=emptyfields");
    exit();


} else if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    header("Location: ../form.php?error=invalidmail");
    exit();
}
else if(!is_numeric($telefoonnummer)){
    header("Location: ../form.php?error=invalidphone");
    exit();
}
else{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO aanmelding (naam, email, personen, telefoonnummer, bedrijf) VALUES (:naam, :email, :personen, :telefoonnummer, :bedrijf)";
    $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);

    $statement->execute([
        'naam' => $naam,
        'email' => $email,
        'personen' => $personen,
        'telefoonnummer' => $telefoonnummer,
        'bedrijf' => $bedrijf,
    ]);
    header("Location: ../form.php?succes=aanmelding");
    exit();
}
```

```html
<?php
$servername = ""; //here is good data for connection
$username = "";//here is good data for connection
$password = "";//here is good data for connection

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=DB3712239", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

in short, yes PDO and prepared statements should be fine.  If you want you could to some further sanitising with the variables (it's good to use a whitelisting approach to specify allowed characters) with some preg_replace/preg_match/str_replace functions, or at least strip_tags to help combat against xxs (assuming you're going to print the info out into a screen somewhere).

I'd say you should use a condition on the execute as you assume it's added correctly, maybe think about saying. `if(...execute()){////}else{direct to an error page})`.  but that's not a security thing at all

Comment: also it's probably best to print out a generic message rather than` $e->getMessage()` in production code, and just turn this on for testing - just in case It prints out something you don't want a muggle to see

Comment: also also I noticed your place markers in the query don't match the place markers in your execute array.  I think I read somewhere recently that you no longer need to use the `:` at the start of place markers anymore but I don't know how accurate that is.  You should check that it's actually saving the data and not just redirecting you to your success page because you didn't use an if

Comment: It is inserting it correctly! Thanks for the feedback, my main questions was is it save and you answered that thanks.